# Add unicode character to Cognos Analytics expression data

Tags: unicode, expression, analytics, cognos

I've got a simple expression like this: ReportDate()
which will print out the timestamp when the report was executed.

I want to add an unicode character like the SUM SIGN (https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2211/index.htm) to that data in that expression. It is not a text field, it needs to be a concatination to a data expression.

Any idea? A simple || ... (any HTML or text)  doesn't work.

Version Cognos Analytics 11
Database is DB2 LUW

Edit: The expression looks like this:

```
case when 
[Datasource].[D_FINRP_D_KONTRAHENT_K].[SL_KONTRAHENTENGRUPPE] like 'D%' then concat('D (Summe)';' ∑') 
else [Datasource].[D_FINRP_D_KONTRAHENT_K].[SL_KONTRAHENTENGRUPPE] 
end
```

The HTML in the Cognos report looks like this: D (Summe)
and then the SUM sign doesn't show up.

Comment: Is it the concat? try concat('D (Summe)',' ∑')
or maybe 'D (Summe)' + ' ∑'

Comment: That's what I tried.

Comment: as funny as it may sound, is it possible that [SL_KONTRAHENTENGRUPPE] has a value of D (Summe)?

Also, try to isolate the issue.  Make a simple data item in a list with just concat('A', 'B')  and see if that works (I thought the semicolon ; might be something to do with it)

Answer (score 0):

Provided you using a Report Expression aka a Layout calculation from the Insertable objects pane, you should be able to use the following expression:

timestamp2string (ReportDate ())+ '∑'

Comment: This works, but the expression I added to my first post still doesn't work. Any idea on that particluar expression?

Comment: @Xenobiologist   Providing more detail than 'still doesn't work' could be helpful.   The first thing to check is what the error is. The error message could give you some idea about what is being complained about.

Also, break the expression into smaller bits to see where the error happens.  For example, just try timestamp2string (ReportDate ()). Then try the '∑'.  Then try something like '∑'  + '∑'.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I edited my first post. There is no error message. The sum sign just doesn't show up. It is converted to some unknown char and not displayed correctly. I can see that there is a char in the HTML of the report result when pressing F12 in firefox to inspect the html code.

Comment: Although repetition makes perfect, it would have been nice to have the right expression from the onset.   That being said the following expression works for me without issue:

case  when 
[Product line] like 'Camping Equipment' then
'∑'+[Product line] 
else
[Product line]
end

So maybe its your like clause or the concat?

Comment: Sorry another quick thought,  does the Sigma render if your report output is PDF?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a *Query calculation*, try an *HTML item* using a *Data item value*.  Your expression should look like:

```
[Sales (query)].[Branch].[City] + '&Sigma;'
```

Here's an example using the sample data.

```
<report xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/report/14.3/" useStyleVersion="11.4" expressionLocale="en-us">
    <drillBehavior/>
    <layouts>
        <layout>
            <reportPages>
                <page name="Page1">
                    <style>
                        <defaultStyles>
                            <defaultStyle refStyle="pg"/>
                        </defaultStyles>
                    </style>
                    <pageBody>
                        <style>
                            <defaultStyles>
                                <defaultStyle refStyle="pb"/>
                            </defaultStyles>
                        </style>
                        <contents>
                            <list horizontalPagination="true" name="List1" refQuery="Query1">
                                <noDataHandler>
                                    <contents>
                                        <block>
                                            <contents>
                                                <textItem>
                                                    <dataSource>
                                                        <staticValue>No Data Available</staticValue>
                                                    </dataSource>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <CSS value="padding:10px 18px;"/>
                                                    </style>
                                                </textItem>
                                            </contents>
                                        </block>
                                    </contents>
                                </noDataHandler>
                                <style>
                                    <CSS value="border-collapse:collapse"/>
                                    <defaultStyles>
                                        <defaultStyle refStyle="ls"/>
                                    </defaultStyles>
                                </style>
                                <listColumns>
                                    <listColumn>
                                        <listColumnTitle>
                                            <style>
                                                <defaultStyles>
                                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                </defaultStyles>
                                            </style>
                                            <contents>
                                                <textItem>
                                                    <dataSource>
                                                        <staticValue>HTML item</staticValue>
                                                    </dataSource>
                                                </textItem>
                                            </contents>
                                        </listColumnTitle>
                                        <listColumnBody>
                                            <style>
                                                <defaultStyles>
                                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="lc"/>
                                                </defaultStyles>
                                            </style>
                                            <contents>
                                                <HTMLItem>
                                                    <dataSource>

                                                        <dataItemValue refDataItem="City"/>
                                                    </dataSource>
                                                </HTMLItem>
                                            </contents>
                                        </listColumnBody>
                                    </listColumn>
                                </listColumns>
                            </list>
                        </contents>
                    </pageBody>
                </page>
            </reportPages>
        </layout>
    </layouts>
    <XMLAttributes>
        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_CreateExtendedDataItems" value="true"/>
        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_modelModificationTime" value="2015-11-25T21:38:24.820Z"/>
        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="listSeparator" value=","/>
    </XMLAttributes>
    <modelPath>/content/folder[@name=&apos;Samples&apos;]/folder[@name=&apos;Models&apos;]/package[@name=&apos;GO sales (query)&apos;]/model[@name=&apos;model&apos;]</modelPath>
    <queries>
        <query name="Query1">
            <source>
                <model/>
            </source>
            <selection>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="City">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Branch].[City] + &apos;&amp;Sigma;&apos;</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
            </selection>
        </query>
    </queries>
</report>
```